# Custom joomla template

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have just started learning to convert html to joomla template 2.5,quite succeed.

My html looks like:

```
Home Page:Header,Menu,slider,footer
About Page:Header,menu,content area,footer.
```

Problem is how to create the about page as well as other pages, I have approx different themes for different pages, header, footer, menu are same, just the middle portion are different.

Suppose I have a main center div

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
<a href="">  <img width="970" height="400" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/sldier1.jpg" alt="Black Leather Suit" title="" /></a></div></div>
```

ow could I add more than 1 components in slider-wrapper div?

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="content" style="none" />
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="content" style="none" />
```

Comment: You're only allowed to have one component on a page in Joomla. You're question doesn't make much sense though so if this doesn't answer it you need to make it clearer!!

Comment: Or are you asking how to add another image in the image slider?

Answer (score 1):

Joomla sites are not like html sites. You don't manually create each page and save the html file. For this you create a new article in the Joomla backend using the article manager or a 3rd party extensions such as K2, or assign an installed component layout to a menu item.

You can also only have 1 component per page however, if you slider comes with a module, then you can load the module in an article by giving is a custom position and then adding the following code to you article:

```
{loadposition xxx}
```